# Yet Another getting text file into Arraylist

Tags: java, text, arraylist

I'm trying to get each element on each line in a text file so I can perform calculations from line to line. The problem is that I'm only able to get each individual element from my text. I'd like to be able to point to line 50 and extract the first element, the second, the third-then go to line 51 and do the same.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadWithScanner {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/evanlivingston/2.txt"));
            List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();{
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                doubles.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            }
            for( int counter=0; counter<doubles.size(); counter++ ) {
                // j=i+1 to calculate the distance between two points only once, 
                // not one way and back; also skip calculating distance between 
                // the same point
                for( int j=counter+1; j<doubles.size(); j++ ) { 
                    Double c1 = doubles.get(counter);
                    Double c2 = doubles.get(j); 
            System.out.println(c1 - c2);    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

My text file looks like:

0 10 12 4 5 6

0 10 12 4 5 7

...
20 20 20 20 20 20

Comment: Could you reword the question a little bit. It is a little difficult to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Why do you have a nested loop?

Comment: You said you want to extract the 1st, 2nd and 3rd element of each line but it seems that each line has 6 elements. Are you skipping elements 4 to 6 by purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            doubles.add(scanner.nextDouble());
        }
```

You are doing something wrong if your intent is to parse each double in a line and there are multiple lines.
I think you need something like:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
      String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
      //here iterate the string currentLine to get each double
}
```

Comment: While I would agree it's poor style, it would get them all. The `hasNextLine()` wouldn't skip the remainder of the line.

Comment: @glowcoder: you are right .  Anyway i think his problem is related to get each double for each line, accessing them by line. So it should invoke nextLine() to divide all double in line groups

Comment: @Overbose, I'm trying to load the whole text into memory before I start iterating through lines and doing my calculations, Your proposed solution does not allow this correct?

Comment: @Evan it would still be possible to do that even loading it all, but 1, you're not loading the whole text into memory even now, and two why would you?

Comment: @glowcoder, I'm performing calculations on every line in a file with every other line, if I have 60,000 lines I'm creating  3,600,000,000 lines. I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @user690201: yes it does. You can load whole text into memory whatever like you want. But like @Evans said you are not doing that

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on 0verbose's answer: It seems like you want to get the elements by line, i.e. later you'd want to know which line the double was in.

Thus, try using a `List<List<Double>>` and create a sublist with the doubles for each line.
If all lines have the same number of elements you could use a single list and then use `index = line_no * num_elements_per_line + element_index_in_line` to address a specific element.